# Can a Python package depend on a specific version control revision of another Python package?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, easy-install, pip

Some useful Python packages are broken on pypi, and the only acceptable version is a particular revision in a revision control system. Can that be expressed in `setup.py` e.g

`requires = 'svn://example.org/useful.package/trunk@1234'` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do two things.  First, require the exact version you want, e.g.:

```
install_requires = "useful.package==1.9dev-r1234"
```

and then include a `dependency_links` setting specifying where to find it:

```
dependency_links = ["svn://example.org/useful.package/trunk@1234#egg=useful.package-1.9dev-r1234"]
```

Note that the version `#egg=` part of the `dependency_links` URL must *exactly* match what you specified in `install_requires`; this is what links the two pieces together.

What happens is that setuptools sees the #egg tag on the link and saves the URL as an available download URL for that precise version of the package.  Then, when it tries to resolve that requirement later, it should download that precise SVN URL.

(Note, however, that for this to *really* work, the targeted SVN revision has to actually build an egg with that name and version.  Otherwise, your dependency will fail at runtime!  So, this really only works if the package you're depending on uses SVN revision tags in their default build version numbers.)

Comment: Yep, it doesn't /really/ work in the common case... I just use pip now.

Comment: shouldn't "find_links" actually be "dependency_links" ?

Comment: The `#egg=` part of your `dependency_links` url doesn't exactly match what you specified in `install_requires`: it uses a `-` where your `install_requires` uses a `==`. Which parts of the string must match exactly?

Answer (score 2):

If you really require an obscure version of another package, and there's no way to make do with other versions, you might want to simply distribute that version of the package with your own. If necessary put it in your own namespace to ensure that your version is the one that is used.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't figured out how to reference this from `setup.py` but `pip` can check out specific revisions of Python packages with a simple requirements file. With a requirements file called `requires.txt`, `pip install -r requires.txt` will install all the packages listed in that file (and their dependencies).

Here is part of my requirements file. The lines starting with `-e` check out specific revisions of packages from version control (git, svn, or mercurial), including my project, and install them in an editable form. `pip freeze` lists all installed packages in this format.

`requires.txt`:

```
-e hg+file:///home/me/my-private-project#egg=myproject
-e hg+http://bitbucket.org/ianb/webob@tip#egg=WebOb
-e svn+http://svn.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/trunk@6638#egg=SQLAlchemy
-e svn+http://svn.zope.org/repos/main/z3c.saconfig/trunk@106508#egg=z3c.saconfig
## The following requirements were added by pip --freeze:
APScheduler==1.01
simplejson==2.0.9
... (many more)
```

Comment: Do you really want to have editable form of your dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You can release packages of specific versions, but you have to distribute them together. There is no way to automatically download them with standard Python.

However, you can use Buildout and create a buildout.cfg that makes it possible to replicate the environment. It can check out and install specific revisions if you use extensions like mr.developer.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer