# How to make setup.py install a different module

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, setuptools

I would like to use `distutils` (`setup.py`) to be able to install a python package (from a local repository), which requires another package from a different local repository. Since I am lacking decent documentation of the `setup` command (I only found some examples 
 [here](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/distutils/examples.html), confused by `setup`-terms  `extras_require`, `install_require` and `dependency_links` found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572603/specifying-optional-dependencies-in-pypi-python-setup-py) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472430/how-can-i-make-setuptools-install-a-package-thats-not-on-pypi)), does anyone have a complete `setup.py` file that shows how this can be handled, i.e. that `distutils` handles the installation of a package found in some SVN repository, when the main package I am installing right now requires that?

More detailed explanation: I have two local svn (or git) repositories `basicmodule`  and `extendedmodule`. Now I checkout `extendedmodule` and run `python setup.py install`. This `setup.py` files knows that `extendedmodule` requires `basicmodule`, and automatically downloads it from the repository and installs it (in case it is not installed yet). How can I solve this with `setup.py`? Or maybe there is another, better way to do this?

---

**EDIT: Followup question**

Based on the answer by Tom I have tried to use a `setup.py` as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name = "extralibs",
    version = "0.0.2",
    description = ("Some extra libs."),
    packages=['extralib'],
    install_requires = "basiclib==1.9dev-r1234",
    dependency_links = ["https://source.company.xy/svn/MainDir/SVNDir/basiclib/trunk@20479#egg=basiclib-1.9dev-r1234"]
```

)

When trying to install this as a normal user I get the following error:

```
error: Can't download https://source.company.xy/svn/MainDir/SVNDir/basiclib/trunk@20479: 401 Authorization Required
```

But when I do a normal `svn` checkout with the exact same link it works:

```
svn co https://source.company.xy/svn/MainDir/SVNDir/basiclib/trunk@20479
```

Any suggestion how to solve this without changing ANY configuration of the svn repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your svn client is authentified (caching realm somewhere in ~/.subversion directory) what your distutils http client don't know how to do.

Distutils supports svn+http link type in dependency links. So you may try adding "svn+" before your dependency link providing username and password:

> dependency_links =
>   ["svn+https://user:password@source.company.xy/svn/MainDir/SVNDir/basiclib/trunk@20479#egg=basiclib-1.9dev-r1234"]

For security reasons you should not put your username and password in your setup.py file. One way to do that it fetching authentication information from an environment variable or event try to fetch it from your subversion configuration directory (~/.subversion)

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answers to these two questions. They both give specific examples on how `install_requires` and `dependency_links` work together to achieve what you want.

- [Can Pip install dependencies not specified in setup.py at install time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150423/can-pip-install-dependencies-not-specified-in-setup-py-at-install-time)
- [Can a Python package depend on a specific version control revision of another Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087492/can-a-python-package-depend-on-a-specific-version-control-revision-of-another-py)