# How-to configure svn dependency link in setuptools

Tags: python, svn, setuptools

I have a `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='MyCartridge',
      version='1.0',
      description='My Cartridge',
      author='First Last',
      author_email='info@example.com',
      url='http://www.example.com/',
      install_requires=[
                        'CustomFieldAdminPlugin-0.2.8-r13289'
      ],
      dependency_links = [
                        'http://trac-hacks.org/svn/customfieldadminplugin/0.11#egg=CustomFieldAdminPlugin-0.2.8-r13289'
      ],
     )
```

When I run it, setuptools fails to checkout sources with error:

```
Can't download http://trac-hacks.org/svn/customfieldadminplugin/0.11#egg=CustomFieldAdminPlugin-0.2.8-r13289: 400 Bad Request
```

I tried to use `svn+http`, `0.11#egg`, `0.11/#egg`, `0.11@13289#egg`, `0.11?p=13289#egg` and it still fails to checkout.

What I did wrong?

Comment: I strongly recommend you do not use dependency links *at all*, see [Additional actions in setup.py for install](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/223267)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Python package depend on a specific version control revision of another Python package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087492/can-a-python-package-depend-on-a-specific-version-control-revision-of-another-py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was discovered that by default there was `setuptools-0.6` installed at the server. After upgrading to `setuptools-2.1` the problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation: http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi

you should use `svn+URL` for Subversion or as a more complete version
`vcs+proto://host/path@revision#egg=project-version`

So you should try `svn+http://trac-hacks.org/svn/customfieldadminplugin/0.11 @13289#egg=CustomFieldAdminPlugin-0.2.8-r13289`

Works for me btw.